# SQL Query Summarize Table

Tags: sql

This is question that I got from an interviewer, which I wasn't able to answer then. This is all the information that he gave me. I found this question is confusing, but maybe someone can guess what he meant to ask.

I have table Movie:

```
Movie_ID Producer  

1         Ann  
1         Bill  
2         Joe  
3         Ann
```

Target output:

```
Movie_ID  Number of Movies with same Producer  
1         2 
2         1  
3         1
```

How to write the SQL query?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want the number of producers per movie? If so the column name in the desired results is confusing.

Comment: This is a question that I got from an interviewer. That's all the information he gave me, and I wasn't able to answer the question then. So I put it here for your opinions. Now I see that his question is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
select movie_id, count(1) as "Number of movies with same producer"
from   movie
group by movie_id
```

Comment: What is the meaning of count(1)?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Joe There's no link here. Please only use auto comments when they apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Movie_ID , COUNT(*) AS [Number Of Movies]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Movie_ID
```